# How to add space around tcolorbox theorem

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

In `amsthm` you can easily change the space before and after a theorem. Can this be done with `tcolorbox`  theorem? If so, how? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}
Add space below this text.

\begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
in this example, prefixed with the section number.
\end{mytheo}

Add space above this text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? ;-)

Comment: It should be possible using `\newtcbtheorem`  -- the options passed to this declaring command will go to the underlying `tcolorbox`. Something like `before skip=0.5in` and `after skip=0.3in` perhaps

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added an MWE. I also tried the options you suggested, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`before skip` and `after skip` provide such spaces.  You will not notice them if they are too small.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,before
skip=20pt plus 2pt,after skip=20pt plus 2pt}{th}

\begin{document}
Add space below this text.

\begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
in this example, prefixed with the section number.
\end{mytheo}

Add space above this text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, these options weren't recognized when I tried to use them. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What version of the package do you have? If you add `\listfiles` to your document, the version information will be printed in the `.log` file.  My version is `tcolorbox.sty    2015/03/16 version 3.50`

Comment: Mine is `tcolorbox.sty 2014/05/18 version 3.04`, so that explains it.

Comment: I try to keep my whole distribution up-to-date, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/15925.  I am using texlive 2014, awaitng TL2015.

Comment: Let me make sure everything works when it's finished updating, and then I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Works great. I have one more question though: why do you use `20pt plut 2pt` instead of just `22pt`?

Comment: Good to hear this works.  I partly choose this as illustration that it is glue (stretchable space) instead of just a dimension; it means the space will be somewhere between `20pt` and `22pt`.  It is usually a good idea to include some flexibility, particularly if your document is flush bottom (often the default), to give LaTeX some extra freedom in spacing elements on the page.  Many standard environments have space with some glue.

Answer (score 2):

Do `before` and `after` options serve to you? They are explained in section *4.15 Embedding into the Surroundings*, page 75.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, before={\vspace{2cm}}, after={\vspace{1cm}}}{th}

\begin{document}
Add space below this text.

\begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
in this example, prefixed with the section number.
\end{mytheo}

Add space above this text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution causes my theorems to be indented. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with `after`, only with `before`.